# accessing nested objects in mongo using node.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I'm unable to access a nested object in a mongo doc. None of the online solutions or even mongo documentation has been able to resolve my problem.

```
{
 characterName:character.characterName,
 0:{slotName:"", slotCount:0},
 1:{slotName:"", slotCount:0},
 2:{slotName:"", slotCount:0},
 3:{slotName:"", slotCount:0}
}
```

I want to access any of the numbered keys via an api and change the value of slotCount.

I've tried everything I could find online including the below.

```
db.Inventories.updateOne(
  {characterName:user.selectedCharacter.CharacterName},
  {$set:{[req.query.slotNumber].0.slotCount:req.query.itemCount}}
);
```

I'm getting syntax errors from VSCode as it's not expecting a period . after the first key on the last line of code.

SOLUTION: create a var that stores a string

```
key =`${req.query.slotNumber}.slotCount`
```

and then use square brackets when calling the key

```
db.Inventories.updateOne(
 {characterName:user.selectedCharacter.CharacterName},
 {$inc:{[key]:-1}}
```

Comment: If `req.query.slotNumber` contains the slot, then `.0` would be extraneous.

Comment: my first attempt omitted the .0 but still have the same error. The .0 was suggested by some of the solutions I found. 

VSCode is not expecting anything else to come before the colon besides the key name.

Comment: In order to have a fieldname that contains a dot, you will need to quote it.  The basic query you are looking for is https://mongoplayground.net/p/caIectVB5-X